# How to programatically call a button that runs as an independent task?

Tags: java, swing, conways-game-of-life

I have implemented [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) problem in Java swing. Everything is working fine. As you can see in the screenshot below, whenever the "Tick" button is clicked, the game progresses to the next life form. Now, I am planning to include an "Autoplay" button alongside "Tick" button. The purpose of this autoplay is simple. When I hit it, an automated operation should carry on as if I am pressing tick button at an interval of 1 second.

[image]

I tried this. But this seems to block all the other operations. How to do this action in a separate thread? A small code snippet would get me going.

```
class AutoPlayListener implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == btnAutoPlay){
      while(true){
        Thread.sleep(1000); //InterruptedException try catch hidden
        btnTick.doClick();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're sleeping the main event listener thread which is why nothing else is working. To run this sort of operation try having a high level thread reference which you use to modify the game state. Start and stop said thread as needed. I don't remember enough Java to help with your code snippet though. Sorry.

Comment: See also [How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) for some tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `javax.swing.Timer`.  It will be able to work with the existing `ActionListener` if the `while(true)` and `Thread.sleep()` calls are removed.

Comment: +1. Thank you! My program reached completion!!! Here is the changeset! https://github.com/technicalypto/Games/commit/d67c84ff2d9dd3c59f88c77d679e7e2e4b90998d

Comment: BTW - note that 1) The `PlayGround` class is missing from the github sources.  2) A great thing for launching Java rich client apps. off web sites is [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Plyaground class is there at the source, double checked it. And thanks for hinting Java WS as well! I am planning to post this in my blog..

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. Start a new thread. The thread will contain the while loop, and execute a method that processes the array. In each iteration, call `repaint()` or `invalidate()` on your window to tell it that it needs redrawing.
2. Use a Timer. The GUI thread will call your routine at regular intervals.

### Threads:

In `actionPerformed` method, create a new Thread. and call its start method.
The `Runnable` of the thread should run a while loop (as you have already done), and then simply exit.

### Timer:

Create an object in your class of type Timer. Use the one in `java.swing.Timer` if you are using swing (there is also `java.util.Timer` which isn't good for GUI ops). The timer should have an `ActionListener` that calls your method once, but the Timer has a repeat rate of 1000ms.

### Tips

1. to invoke the action, you should put it in a separate method, rather than directly under the button handler. That way, you aren't calling GUI stuff from outside the GUI thread.

e.g.

```
tickButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    doTick();
  }
});
```

1. The mechanism to stop the thread is equally important! In general, don't use a `while(true)` in a thread as it will get lost; invent a semaphore to terminate it.
2. use a `JToggleButton` rather than `Button`?
3. Synchronization:
    If you use threads, you will need something like this, to prevent new threads being created each time the button is pressed:

Code

```
Thread autoplayThread = null;
Object lock;
boolean autoplaying = false;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  synchronized(lock){ // prevent any race condition here
    if(!autoplaying && autoplayThread==null ){
      autoplaying = true; 
      autoplayThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
          try{ 
            while(autoplaying){  ....  }
          }finally{
            synchronized(lock) {
              autoplaying=false;
              autoplayThread=null;
            }
          }
        }
      });
      autoplayThread.start();
    }else{ // stop the thread!
      autoplaying=false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was about to vote your answer down for mentioning the `java.util.Timer` - until I noticed you also advised against it and mentioned the Swing `Timer`. So +1.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ranman said you're blocking main UI thread. I believe [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) is usually used for things like this.

Comment: +1 i agree. invokeLater is good for such things. in fact, i have done this for a similar project.